# How to make a Java Application faster?

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a billing daemon that must process hundred thousands of data in a very fast manner. I implemented `ExecutorSerivce` for parallel processing. It did increase the speed but not very much. It takes approx 2.5-3 hours to process 1,00,000 records. How can I make it more faster like processing those data within half an hour?

I have written the following for execution setting:

```
-Xms2048M -Xmx2048M -XX:MaxPermSize=256m
```

I tried to implement a Producer Consumer model with 1 producer and 4 consumers.  Each list can contain 10,000 records.

```
ArrayBlockingQueue<BillableList> list =new ArrayBlockingQueue<BillableList>(10);

ExecutorService threadPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
threadPool.execute(new Consumer("pool1", list)); 
threadPool.execute(new Consumer("pool2", list));
threadPool.execute(new Consumer("pool3", list));
threadPool.execute(new Consumer("pool4", list));
Future producerStatus = threadPool.submit(new Producer("Producer", list)); 
producerStatus.get(); 
threadPool.shutdown();
```

I also get a lot of "database lock wait timeout exceeded" exceptions while updating records to the database. Is it due to different consumers trying for the same user at the same time? How can I make different consumers take different data from `ArrayBlockingQueue`'s list?

Comment: Step 1: find out why it's slow. Log execution times of high-level operations, use a profiler, do GC logging to see if you're trashing memory...

Comment: Get a very fast SSD array for the DB.

Comment: also ~purrrrformance~~~~

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The only possible answer to this is "Use a profiler and find out why it's slow". You can't do anything about a problem when you don't know where the problem is. What are you going to, pick a random function and micro-optimize it? Profiler data or nothing will ever, ever happen.

Comment: The only possible answer?  Really?

Comment: @Gray: Your answer is mostly speculation. The fact that speculating was all you could do shows the correctness of what I have said.

Comment: Speculation it is but "running a profiler" is the easy answer -- especially if the OP talks about db contention.

Comment: It's also the *accurate* answer.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I make it more faster like processing those data within half an hour?

If adding threads did not help then chances are you are being limited not my CPU but by some other factor.  Most likely disk or network IO.  As mentioned, profiling your code should show you the culprit.

> I also get a lot of "database lock wait timeout exceeded" exceptions while updating records to the database.

And there's your big clue.  Regardless of how many threads are working on a the job, if they are all waiting for the database then adding threads is not making it faster.

Here are some ideas:

- Increase the physical speed of your database box.  SSDs can provide wondrous improvements for IO intensive operations.  Increasing the memory can also give a big win because of disk cache.
- Consider sharding your data and writing to multiple database instances.  This may not be possible given your schema.
- Consider turning off auto-commit and manually committing after every ~100 or so operations.
- Watch out for indexes.  If you are doing some sort of bulk load, often if you turn off indexes your inserts will run faster.  Adding the indexes at the end takes a while but still is a win.
- Also, if you are doing queries, make sure you have good indexes where needed.  Check your database logs to see which queries are taking too long to see if you are missing some indexes in key places.

Comment: @Gray..   System is on Amazon EC2 and mysql database is on RDS. The query takes like 10 secs to retrieve 10,000 records!! I will try the profiler and see what's happening inside!! Thanks.. !!

Comment: A profiler is a good idea but I'm not sure that's going to help much.  You are going to see that it is spending its time in JDBC wich means waiting for the db connection.  Best of luck @MadanMadan.

Comment: @Gray - yeah, that's a slam-dunk. If it's a networked DB, or hosted on a spinner, you're stuft.

Comment: @Gray.. You just hit at the right target!! How can I improve it? Any suggestion!! JDBC part!!

Comment: I would post another question @MadanMadan specifically around improving the performance of RDS.  Do your research first.  They may be things that you can improve on.  However, you may want to change your architecture if you are retrieving a lot of 10k record result sets.